# How do you find the rightmost digit of an integer?

Tags: math

Assume that an int  variable `x` that has already  been declared,

write an expression  whose value  is the last (rightmost) digit of `x`.

I know the answer is `x%10`, but why is that the expression that reveals the rightmost digit?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: This is not a Java question but a question about middle school math.

Comment: References to Java removed. The question is language-agnostic.

Comment: It's actualy `x % y` where `y` is the base in which `x` is represented.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a conceptual programming question

Answer (score 19):

`x % 10` looks like the correct answer. But is not.

`-2 % 10` is either `-2` or `8` depending on language/implementation/whatever. And neither is actually "last digit".

So the correct answer is `abs(x) % 10`.

Answer (score 11):

It's Math

When you use the '%' operator you are asking for "What is the remainder after dividing by that number" So if I have 28 % 10  I'm saying "What is the remainder of 28 divided by 10". This, of course, would give me 8. Getting the remainder of a number divided by 10 only leaves you with the ones digit (right most number).

We use a Decimal / Base 10 number system. So if you use 10 you will always get remainders in between 0-9.

In Java, '%' is the remainder operator and works the way described above.

[Summary of Operators in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: With the appropriate sequence of divide and modulo operators, it's possible to extract any other digits as well.

Comment: So if for example x%100 would give me the last two digits and x%1000 would give me the last three right.

Comment: % is not the modulus operator. It's the remainder operator. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx)